# How can i pass two conditions in a jpql query

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpql

How can I pass a jpql query where there is two condition?

Here my example: I want to find the list of "dossier"

```
where DEPI2 = 2 and typedossier = urgent
```

and at the same time I want to find list of dossier

```
where DEPID = 2 and d2.dateCreation <:fiveDaysAhead2
```

Here's my function

```
public List<Dossier> getDossierFindAllParDepartementMidandUrgen() {
    Calendar myFiveDaysAhead2;
    myFiveDaysAhead2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    myFiveDaysAhead2.add(Calendar.DATE, -5);

    TypedQuery<Dossier> query2;
    query2 =
        em.createQuery("SELECT d2 FROM Dossier d2 WHERE d2.depid =:DEPID AND d2.typeDossier = :tpd2 OR " +
                       "d2.dateCreation <:fiveDaysAhead2", Dossier.class);
    query2.setParameter("DEPID","2");
    query2.setParameter("tpd2","Urgent");
    query2.setParameter("fiveDaysAhead2", myFiveDaysAhead2, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);

    return query2.getResultList();
}
```

Here in my case it find all the dossier `where d2.dateCreation <:fiveDaysAhead2`
that means even where `depid = 1` it's listed

Comment: enclose your conditions within parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

query2 =
        em.createQuery("SELECT d2 FROM Dossier d2 WHERE (d2.depid =:DEPID AND d2.typeDossier = :tpd2) OR " +
                       "(d2.dateCreation <:fiveDaysAhead2 AND d2.depid =:DEPID)", Dossier.class);

Comment: or even simpler just by correctly putting parentheses: SELECT d2 FROM Dossier d2 WHERE d2.depid = :DEPID AND (d2.typeDossier = :tpd2 OR d2.dateCreation < :fiveDaysAhead2)